# Shortcut in Netbeans for ClearCase actions

Tags: netbeans, clearcase

Are there keyboard shorcuts for ClearCase actions? In particular I am looking for a shortcut to hijack a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this Clearcase plugin for Netbeans [ http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/clearcase.html ] . It does come with a few key bindings in Netbeans and you can edit the key bindings in Netbeans key binding editor as well.

Comment: I am using that plugin indeed. Can't find "hijack" in shortcut editor though

Comment: @Paolo: that is because you don't need a Clearcase operation to make a file hijacked. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "ClearCase shortcut" to hijack a file, you just need to make that file writable through the OS (Windows/Linux/Mac...).
That is enough to make a file "hijacked" in ClearCase since you didn't do it through a regular "cleartool checkout".

If you need a Netbeans plugin for that, I would recommend "[**netbeans-command-shortcuts**](http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-command-shortcuts/)":

[image: Make writable]

You can assign a shortcut to the "make writable" command (see the [wiki "Configuration"](http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-command-shortcuts/wiki/Configuration)):

[image: shortcut]